# Unity game:HTC-Vive And mouse?

Tags: unity-game-engine, htc-vive

How do you make a unity3D game who support both HTC-Vive headset and mouse controller?

I'm developing a small VR demo for an event with a team, for the controller HTC Vive (steam)

the issue is, we have only one headset for eleven people.
a solution would be to be able to use the mouse instead of the head.
GoogleVR allow to do it(when you press Alt in dev mode), but it don't work with Vive.

Any idea of how and why?
Any plugin who support both, vive and the mouse/waspd?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can make control with mouse like in first person games. Track your mouse movement and rotate your 'VR' camera.

Comment: the issue is, I need both. And if I modify the plugin script, it will be deleted with the plugins update.
Also, I need to know if the Vive part still work.

Comment: Hmm.. There is a "LateUpdate()" function in unity. Try to recognize mouse offset x and y and than do something like "transform.rotate" in vr camera